# Google Maps / Autocomplete and Flask form using flask_wtf

Tags: python, html, flask, google-maps-api-3, google-location-services

I'm using for my forms flask_wtf and Jinja2 so when I have an error the page is not submitted and the error appears below the field - except for one field which is the address because we used Google Maps / Autocomplete API.

Do We have a way to combine those two?
If not, what is the best way to handle errors?
Another question - When the user has details in the DB and he changes the address - works fine,
but if the user changes, for example, its shop name - the form is neither in GET request nor form.validate_on_submit(), it's in POST and I think it has to do with the location, I cannot figure it out.

**form.py**

```
    class SellerForm(FlaskForm):
    shop_name = StringField(label='Shop Name', validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=2, max=50)])
    domain = SelectField(label='Domain', choices=DOMAINS, validate_choice=True, validators=[InputRequired()])
    image_file = FileField(label='Logo Image', validators=[FileAllowed(['jpg', 'png'])])
    submit = SubmitField(label='Set')
```

**app.py**

```
    @bp.route('/settings', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    @login_required
    def settings():
        with DBSession() as session_db:
            form = SellerForm()
            if form.validate_on_submit():
                seller = session_db.query(Seller).filter_by(id=current_user.get_id()).first()
                if form.image_file.data:
                    image_file = save_image(form.image_file.data)
                    seller.image_file = image_file
                lat = request.form['lat']
                lng = request.form['lng']
                location = session_db.query(Location).filter_by(seller_id=current_user.get_id()).first()
                if not location:
                    location = Location(current_user.get_id(), form.address.data, lat, lng)
                    session_db.add(location)
                else:
                    location.set_settings(form.address.data, lat, lng)
                seller.set_settings(form.shop_name.data, form.domain.data)
                session_db.commit()
                flash(f'Settings were updated for {form.shop_name.data}!', 'success')
                return redirect(url_for(".history"))
            elif request.method == 'GET':
                form.shop_name.data = current_user.shop_name
                form.domain.data = current_user.domain
                location = session_db.query(Location).filter_by(seller_id=current_user.get_id()).first()
                if location is not None:
                    form.address.data = location.address
            return render_template('seller_form.html', form=form, title='Settings', seller=1)
```

**html**

```
    {% extends "layout.html" %}
    {% block head %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
        <script>
            function initialize() {
              var input = document.getElementById('search_input');
              var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
                google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
                    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                    document.getElementById('loc_lat').value = place.geometry.location.lat();
                    document.getElementById('loc_lng').value = place.geometry.location.lng();
                });
            }
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
        <script>
            function outputUpdate(radius) {
                document.querySelector('#selected-radius').value = radius;
            }
        </script>
    {% endblock head %}
    
    {% block content %}
        <h1>Settings</h1>
        <div class="content-section">
            <form method= "POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {{ form.csrf_token }}
    
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Shop Details</legend>
    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.shop_name.label(class="form-control-label") }}
    
                        {% if form.shop_name.errors %}
                            {{ form.shop_name(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in form.shop_name.errors %}
                                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        {% else %}
                            {{ form.shop_name(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Location</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="search_input" name="address" placeholder= "Type address" value="{{ form.address.data }}"/>
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="loc_lat" name="lat" />
                        <input type="hidden" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="loc_lng" name="lng" />
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.domain.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                        {% if form.domain.errors %}
                            {{ form.domain(class="form-control form-control-lg is-invalid") }}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {% for error in form.domain.errors %}
                                    <span>{{ error }}</span>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </div>
                        {% else %}
                            {{ form.domain(class="form-control form-control-lg", size="3") }}
                        {% endif %}
                        <br>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form.image_file.label() }}
                            {{ form.image_file(class="form-control-file custom-file-upload") }}
                            {% if form.image_file.errors %}
                                {% for error in form.image_file.errors %}
                                    <span class="text-danger">{{ error }}</span></br>
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
    
                </fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-dark") }}
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    
    {% endblock content %}
```

Comment: What's wrong with a `{% if form.search_input.errors %}` block like you've done with your other inputs?

Comment: As I understand it is not an error of the input, it happens when the user doesn't update this field, and we get latitude and longitude zero. 
Anyway, what validations should we use and where to write them? would you please suggest?

Comment: If 0, 0 is not a valid input then update your form to not validate it. Then display the appropriate error in your jinja2 template.

Comment: I did it yesterday and it worked, thanks. Do you have any recommendations on how to check if the string is not a valid address? (for example "sfsdfdsf").

Comment: I've never used Google's autocomplete so I don't think I'd be any help with that part.